In open-api-maven-plugin, how to mark specific parameter not to be generated when generating the client jar?
I have this configuration, how to avoid the Test-Token from being added in the final openapi client and thus this methods signature will not be test(String testToken) but test()
...
"paths": {
    "/test": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "test-controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "checkTest",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Test-Token",
            "in": "header",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "default": "test"
            },
          }
        ],
...

I tried to add 'x-codegen-parameter' to false in the json but still it gets generated.

Remove it from the parameters?

I want it to be shown in the swagger ui for easy testing, but not when I generate the code.

So you have added an end point in your production code for testing? That's is in general a bad idea ... what does this give what the other part do not? Test the production code and not "special test code"...

"test" is hiding the real name of the parameter, and it is not in production. But this is not the case.

The question is can this be done with the current implementation of openapi codegen or I have to modify the source code and add a custom implementation to support my use case?

If you come up this problem, the solution I found is by creating a new version of openapi-generator-maven-plugin adding a custom implementation.
Refer to this repository: https://github.com/lejdiprifti/openapi-generator/tree/ignore-parameters

I believe you were need to take advantage of implicitHeadersRegex option: https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java/

Yes, I think you're right. I had to modify the source code of the tool, only to learn it now. Thanks!
